# ASP.net programmatically bind dataset to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a data set with about 15 columns, and I also have an ASP.net gridview. I was wondering if any one knew how I can populate the gridview with the dataset, but the issue is I just want a few of the columns from the dataset.

at the moment I'm just doing

```
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

but this obviously binds all the columns from the dataset to the gridview.

Comment: Then you can select the those few columns into the data set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you are looking to create columns at runtime?  Try this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamic_Columns_in_Grid.aspx

Alternatively, you can configure your gridview ahead of time in the aspx:

```
<Columns> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="ProductName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="Price" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
</Columns>
```

And make sure you set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to false.

Answer (score 7):

The GridView by default will automatically generate all of the columns based on the data being bound.

Set `GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false` and then define the columns you want through the `GridView.Columns` Property.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can see to do this, depending on what you can change and what has to stay the way it is:

1) If you have control of the query/proc that generates the dataset, and can do so without adversely affecting other grids/pages, modify the query so that it only SELECTs the columns you use. You can still use non-selected columns in JOIN and WHERE, and you get the added bonus of not having to add every column to ORDER BY.

2) If you only have control of the grid and the codebehind that's used to generate it, you can set as a DataGrid parameter, the AutoGenerateColumns = false, and then nest within your DataGrid, the BoundFields you need to show. This also allows you the power to format, make column names, etc.

If you can do both of these things, your Grid should load faster, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Set the grids AutoGeneratedColumns to false, and set the Columns you want to use in the gridview designer or in code. But you have to set the DataField property on column to the same as the name of

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select required fields from YourTable, conn);

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
GridView1.DataBind();

rdr.Close();
```

This will print only required fields.